# Verify Active Directory domain trust relationship of the local machine

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, active-directory

I have to find out if the local machine is still joined to a domain, or if another computer has used the computer account or, if the computer account has been reset.

In other words, i need to verify the trust relationship between the local machine and the domain

NLTest /SC_VERIFY:{Domain} does the job pretty well.

Are there any API functions that i can use to detect whether the local machine has lost the trust relationship to a domain? I don't like to call external executables from my program.

What i tried so far:

- NetGetJoinInformation(): It doesn't realize it.
- DsBind*(): It doesn't realize it. Also tried to call it under the local system account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. After a lot of digging, i finally found a solution: [I_NetLogonControl2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
NETLOGON_INFO_2* buffer=NULL;
LPBYTE domainName = (LPBYTE) L"eng";

int ret = I_NetLogonControl2(NULL, NETLOGON_CONTROL_TC_VERIFY, 2, (LPBYTE) &domainName, (LPBYTE*)&buffer);
wprintf( L"I_NetLogonControl2() returned %i\n", ret);
if (ret==0)
{
    wprintf( L"PdcConenctionStatus: %i\n", buffer->netlog2_pdc_connection_status);
    if (buffer->netlog2_pdc_connection_status==0)
        wprintf(L"Trust relationship verified.\n");
    else
        wprintf(L"Trust relationship FAILED.\n");

    wprintf( L"TcConenctionStatus: %i\n", buffer->netlog2_tc_connection_status);
    wprintf( L"Flags: %i\n", buffer->netlog2_flags);
}

return 0;
```

So the magic thing is hidden in NETLOGON_INFO_2::netlog2_pdc_connection_status.
If this value is 86 (ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD) or 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) the computer account has been changed (or reset).
 
If the computer account has been deleted, the value is 1787 (ERROR_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT)

Hope this helps others!

Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation is not precise. When you are specifying "NETLOGON_CONTROL_TC_VERIFY", the data argument (LPBYTE) must point to (LPWSTR*)!

Answer (score 0):

you can try [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to perform network login (LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK).

If workstation has broken trust with domain, it will not be able to verify your credentials.

You will need some domain credentials which can perform network logon of course, not local.

Your other option is to use local account which has granted network service logon and try to access other domain workstation resource.You can receive access denied error or trust relation failed depends on which resource on which server.

Finally, you can still search system event log for event ID signaling trust failure.

> but we don't have any well known accounts that we can use for this

You can not check for workstation account status on domain site (in AD) until you authenticate somehow, just local status.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That would work, but we don't have any well known accounts that we can use for this -> policy

Answer (score 0):

NetLogon_Control2 is for BDC to PDC communications; does not work for my tests in Win 7

Microsoft page --

**Remarks**

This function can be used to request that a BDC ensure that its copy of the SAM database is brought up-to-date. It can also be used to determine if a **BDC** currently has a secure channel open to the **PDC**.